# DataError: value too long for type character varying(1024) TextField

Tags: django, postgresql

Hello I am having this problem with my Django model. Field is HTMLField from TinyMCE which inherts from Django's TextField so it should be unlimited. Is it possible that db somehow truncated this length? I am inserting string which is about 4k characters long and I am using psql (PostgreSQL) 12.3 as my database. Thanks

Model:

```
class Category(Model):
    page_content_html=HTMLField(_("page content"), blank=True, null=False, default=''),
  
)
```

HTMLField:

```
class HTMLField(models.TextField):
"""
A text area model field for HTML content.

It uses the TinyMCE 4 widget in forms.

Example::

    from django.db.models import Model
    from tinymce import HTMLField

    class Foo(Model):
        html_content = HTMLField('HTML content')
"""
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.tinymce_profile = kwargs.pop('profile', None)
    super(HTMLField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    defaults = {
        'widget': TinyMCE(profile=self.tinymce_profile)
    }
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    # As an ugly hack, we override the admin widget
    if defaults['widget'] == AdminTextareaWidget:
        defaults['widget'] = AdminTinyMCE(profile=self.tinymce_profile)
    return super(HTMLField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

psql:

```
          Sloupec      |          Typ           | Collation | Nullable |                        Implicitně                        
-------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                |           | not null | nextval('product_category_translation_id_seq'::regclass)
 language_code     | character varying(15)  |           | not null | 
 name              | character varying(256) |           | not null | 
 long_name         | character varying(512) |           | not null | 
 page_content_html | text                   |           | not null | 
 master_id         | integer                |           |          | 
 description_html  | text                   |           | not null | 
 page_description  | text                   |           | not null | 
 page_keywords     | character varying(512) |           | not null | 
 page_title        | character varying(256) |           | not null | 
 page_url_slug     | character varying(256) |           | not null |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value too long for type character varying(1024)` is a PostgreSQL error, which indicates your application is trying to insert data into a `VARCHAR(1024)` column. However your table definition doesn't have a column which matches this definition, so I'm wondering if the application is actually trying to insert the data into a different table (for example a table with the same name in a different schema, or even a different database to the one you think it's connecting to).

The following query should identify any `VARCHAR(1024)` columns and provide more clues as to where the application is trying to insert data:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE data_type = 'character varying'
   AND character_maximum_length = 1024;
```

Note the query will only show information for the current database.